# Is there a way to refresh a page when ReactJS error happens?

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to refresh the whole page when any JS error happens? I have unique error that happens very infrequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [Error Boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html). Set up a handler to reload the page. The only caveat is that you have to know the component causing the error. Or you can bootstrap your whole app